# Cross domain cors not working with SignalR

Tags: .net, cors, signalr

Error: Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44360/notificationshub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:3500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddCors(o =>
            o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
            builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3500")
                       .AllowCredentials())
            );
```

Tried as well adding

```
.WithHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access -Control-Request-Headers", "x-requested-with")
```

Client

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost:44360/notificationshub')
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();
```

Anyone had same issue?